# Calling Google Apps Script functions via fetch request is slow

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I am trying to call some specific functions on *Apps Script* bounded to a *Google Document* from my *main.js*. For example, I want to call this test function:

```
const testingEnv = ()=>{
  body.insertParagraph(0, "Hi mom");
}
```

For this I've created this call function:

```
const callGoogleAppsScript = async (token, functionName, paramToSend) => {
    const scripted =
        'my docs id ';
    const postLinkGoogleScript = `https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/${scriptId}:run`;
    const payload = {
        function: functionName,
        parameters: [paramToSend], // in case I need to send data to functions
    };
    try {
        await fetch(postLinkGoogleScript, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/JSON,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(payload),
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Something nu e bun:', error);
        return false;
    }
};
```

And calling my actual function like this: `callGoogleAPIScript(token, 'testingEnv');` where both *token* and *scriptId* are known and they work.

This works but it takes around 3-4 seconds to execute the function on Docs. I've tested how much time the request takes in *main.js* like:

```
console.time();
callGoogleAPIScript(token, 'testingEnv');
console.timeEnd();
```

and is only 10ms. At first, I thought the problem was from Google API and how long it takes to send/receive data so I created a GET and POST request directly to it:

```
const postLinkDocs = `https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/${ID}:batchUpdate`;
    try {
        await fetch(postLinkDocs, {
            method: 'POST / GET',
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
                'Content-Type': 'application/JSON,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                requests: requests,
            }),
        });
```

but this also is done instantly, so the problem is from calling the GAS functions directly. Is there a method for how should I fix this?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and Google Apps Script. Can I ask you the detail of your question? And, in your `testingEnv`, you are using global variables? If my understanding is correct, I cannot know your actual Google Apps Script. Might your global variables affect your current issue? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: The problem is the time it takes to call a function ( not just `testingEnv`, any function even if it's empty ) via my callGoogleAppsScript(). Simply put it, the fetch to `const postLinkGoogleScript = https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/${scriptId}:run;` is slower than a fetch to `Google API` ( as I did in that GET/POST). Note: the script itself is bounded to my docs,

Comment: You mentioned that it takes 3 to 4 seconds to execute the script in docs but, how is this being tested, to clarify, is it that the script returns a response after 4 seconds, that the document shows the data after 4 seconds, any other way to measure this?